# How to create (UEFI) multiboot USB drive?

Tags: multi-boot, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

I want to create multiboot USB flash drive that contains Windows 10, Windows 7 installers and hirens DVD with Windows 10 PE for rescue purposes. And I want to make it compatible with UEFI.

I used to use YUMI tool and it works great for legacy BIOS, but for UEFI it's not good. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here the situation is different, the another question you referring to didn't mention anything about UEFI compatibility, which i think it needs to be asked again.

Comment: YUMI supports UEFI these days.  https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/#Changelog

Answer (score 0):

My favorite tool for this is: http://multibootusb.org/

That being said, this thread reads like a software recommendation post which is off-topic. You're going to get only opinions and software recommendations.