# Creating a multiboot USB with Windows installers from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, usb, multi-boot

Is it possible to create a multiboot USB with Windows installers *from Linux*?

> Note: this is a self answered question since I want to share my methods with the community. I'm aware of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1465802/1001901) but I think my question has nuances that the (possible duplicate) doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

> Using Linux Mint 19 64 bits as host OS. It's quite safe to assume that similar distros and releases, like Ubuntu for example, will behave the same.

### We will need:

- A USB of 16GB.
- ISO images of Windows, in this case Windows 7 and Windows 10 64 bits.

### The process

1. Install `grub-efi-amd64` for GRUB EFI compatibility

   ```
   sudo apt install -y grub-efi-amd64
   ```
2. Format the USB with msdos partition table. The partitions' size have to be enough to hold the unpacked ISOs. In this case, let's just divide the USB in two halves ~8GB each. Both partitions have to be FAT formatted. Mark the first partition as bootable.
3. Mount the USB first partition. Take a note of: wich device is, i.e. `/dev/sdc1`, and the path it is mounted on, i.e. `/media/foo/WIN7/`. From now on, I will use those two examples for the guide.
4. Install GRUB:

   ```
   dirs=(bin dev etc lib lib64 proc sbin sys usr)
   for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
     mkdir /media/foo/WIN7/$dir && sudo mount --bind /$dir /media/foo/WIN7/$dir
   done

   sudo chroot /media/foo/WIN7/

   # chroot environment
   # first we install grub efi

   grub-install --force --removable --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/ /dev/sdc1

   # now we install grub 386

   grub-install --force --removable --target=i386-pc --boot-directory=/ /dev/sdc

   # exit the chroot

   exit
   ```

> WARNING!! Be **very careful** with the next command, since you could remove binded directories. Use tab completion for the paths instead of typing them.

```
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  sudo umount /media/foo/WIN7/$dir && rm -rf /media/foo/WIN7/$dir
done
```

5. Mount the ISOs, and copy their contents to each USB's partitions: Windows 7 into the first partition (you will get the message that boot directory already exists, just merge them), and Windows 10 into the second partition.

### GRUB configuration:

> NOTE: Windows 7 will boot on BIOS only and Windows 10 in EFI only

1. Create under `/media/foo/WIN7/grub` the file `grub.cfg` and put the following content there:

   ```
   set root='(hd0,1)'
   configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```
2. Create under `/media/foo/WIN7/boot/grub` the file `grub.cfg` and put the following content there:

   ```
   menuentry 'Windows 7 installer BIOS' {
     insmod ntldr
     ntldr /bootmgr
   }

   menuentry 'Windows 10 64 bits installer EFI' {
     set root='(hd0,2)'
     chainloader /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
   }
   ```

We are now ready to test if the USB works properly, just boot your machine with  the USB attached, and depending on the BIOS/EFI you will have different options to select between BIOS or EFI, or just the option to boot from USB in older machines.

Comment: This sounds great. I tried the same but ultimately failed. Does it work with Windows 10 on a NTFS formatted partition? The images Microsoft provides can contain a `install.wim` larger than 4 GB. Any explanation on why Windows 10 won't boot on BIOS?

Comment: The format FAT is meant for EFI to work. But in fact I should investigate more on the subject, maybe the second partition can be NTFS. Let me try it and I'll come back, edit the answer and ping you.

Comment: @Hermann Windows 10 can be booted from BIOS, you just have to change the grub config, that its the same to windows 7: `ntldr /bootmgr`. But, for the  sake of example in the guide (one bios one efi) I deemed not useful to boot a windows 64 image from BIOS since modern hardware is almost EFI. What I've done is create a *third* partition with windows 10 32 bits BIOS. But nonetheless you can change this in the grub conf, adding as many entries as you want.